# Get a string after a special character Python RegEx

Tags: python, regex

How can i get a string after a special character?

For example I want to get the string after `/` in

`my_string = "Python/RegEx"`

Output to be : `RegEx`

I tried :

```
h = []
a = [ 'Python1/RegEx1' , 'Python2/RegEx2', 'Python3/RegEx3']

for i in a: 
    h.append(re.findall(r'/(\w+)', i))
print(h)
```

But the output is : `[['RegEx1'], ['RegEx2'], ['RegEx3']]`

I need : `['RegEx1', 'RegEx2', 'RegEx3']`

Thanks in advance

RegEx beginner

Comment: Assuming `h` is defined somewhere (maybe `h = []`?), changing `.append(...)` to `.extend(...)` should work.

Comment: @jedwards yes h is defined. `h= [ ] `

Comment: Should go for a non-regex way, if that's allowed.

Comment: @anubhava 's answer was the one which i was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `[0]` in front of `findall`:

```
>>> h = []
>>> for i in a:
...     res = re.findall(r'/(\w+)', i)
...     if res:
...           h.append(res[0])
...
>>> print (h)
['RegEx1', 'RegEx2', 'RegEx3']
```

Comment: This helps. Thanks @anubhava

Comment: how to strip if we have more than once special character on the same string? `my_string = "/Python/RegEx"` output to be: `RegEx`

Comment: Change regex to `r'/(\w+)$'`

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the list of lists you get with another for loop.

For example:

```
a = [ 'Python1/RegEx1' , 'Python2/RegEx2', 'Python3/RegEx3']

for i in a: 
    h.append(re.findall(r'/(\w+)', i))

for x in h:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

For something like this where you only have one `/` per item, you could use `map` to `.split('/')` each item and then take `.split('/')[1]` from each item to create the list

```
a = [ 'Python1/RegEx1' , 'Python2/RegEx2', 'Python3/RegEx3']
a = list(map(lambda x: x.split('/')[1], a))
# ['RegEx1', 'RegEx2', 'RegEx3']
```

Or *list comprehension*

```
a = [i.split('/')[1] for i in a]
```

Expanded :

```
l = []
for i in a:
    i = i.split('/')
    l.append(i[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.extend()`:

```
for i in a: 
    h.extend(re.findall(r'/(\w+)', i))
```

Using `+=` (just another way to call `.extend`):

```
for i in a: 
    h += re.findall(r'/(\w+)', i)
```

Using unpacking:

```
for i in a: 
    h.append(*re.findall(r'/(\w+)', i))
```